# C++ interop with other languages

Tags: c++, windows, api

Is there a common approach to writing C++ application API in a way simplifying interop with other languages? Maybe something like using a higher-level interface description language to generate C++ interface together with marshalling code for other platforms (.NET, python, ...)?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options.

If you want to interop with .net, you can write [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) wrapper classes. These allow you to write C++ classes that are directly visible from .net, and in their implementation can use your native C++.

Historically, [COM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_Object_Model) was also usesd for this purpose, but it is less popular nowadays.

There is also a library called [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) that will interop with Java and other languages.

**Edit:** It looks like it will be easier on windows 8 with [WinRT components](http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2011/09/build-your-first-winrt-component.html)

Comment: My question is more like if I can have this automatically, without writing boilerplate code (such as C++/CLI wrapper) myself. I actually hesitated to mention SWIG in the question. SWIG looks like going other way around: C++ interface --> API, leading to certain limitations.

Comment: @7vies: We currently do C++/CLI, haven't found a way to make this more streamlined. Note that you can often write the C++/CLI class in a single cpp file, with all methods inlined, which reduces the maintenance hassle somewhat. The situation may improve in the dev tools for Windows 8, as microsoft promoting writing native code for their new WinRT API. http://pwlodek.blogspot.com/2011/09/build-your-first-winrt-component.html

Answer (score 1):

SOAP/WebServices/Corba?

Although it seems like you were thinking tighter (ie.like linker) coupling than that.

Comment: You are right, I'm looking for something lighter. Using web technologies for e.g. application plugins would be an overkill...

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility might be to make `extern "C"` all your publicized API (even if its implementation is in C++).